# Emulate a Bluetooth Device

Tags: android, bluetooth

My treadmill has a bluetooth chipset that it allows it to communicate with an app on my phone called iFit. In the communications, the phone receives information such as my distance traveled and speed, and the phone can set the treadmill's incline.

Instead of using iFit, I'd like to make my own script running on something like raspberry pi.

Is it possible to emulate the iFit bluetooth communications?

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the bluetooth communication using bluetooth snoop logs. I think you will still need to write something to initiate the initial bluetooth connection. Once that is done you can possibly replay the traffic that captured in the bluetooth snoop logs. You can use Android Things on a raspberry pi if you are comfortable with working on the Android platform.